# VBA first array item is always empty

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, loops

The code below I patched togheter from several examples I found online, I am no VBA expert.

But the first item on the `clist` array (and the first item on the dropdown) is always empty, I'm assuming it has something to do with the `redim`s, but I couldn't figure it out.

What could be the issue?

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    ReDim clist(0)
    'If any value is input
    If ComboBox1.Value <> "" Then
        Dim kword As Variant
        Dim product As Variant
        'For each product description in our sheet table
        For Each product In [Produtos[Descrição]].Rows
            'Keyword search
            For Each kword In Split(ComboBox1.Value, " ")
                If InStr(Replace(product.Value, "", " "), kword) And kword <> "" Then
                    'Issue most likely here
                    ReDim Preserve clist(UBound(clist) + 1) As Variant
                    clist(UBound(clist)) = product.Value
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next kword
        Next product
        ComboBox1.list = clist
        'If found something
        If UBound(clist) > 0 Then
            ComboBox1.DropDown
        End If
    'If no Input just show all products, here it doesn't show a blank item
    Else
        ComboBox1.list = [Produtos[Descrição]].Value2
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are increasing the size of your array and only then setting a value to the last index of it.

```
ReDim Preserve clist(UBound(clist) + 1) As Variant 'Increase array size by 1
clist(UBound(clist)) = product.Value 'Set a value to the higher index
```

This way you will never set a value to the `index 0`

Something like this should solve your problem:

```
if clist(Ubound(clist)) <> empty then
    ReDim Preserve clist(UBound(clist) + 1) As Variant
end if
clist(UBound(clist)) = product.Value
```

Answer (score 4):

Try it as,

```
    ReDim clist(0)
    For Each product In [Produtos[Descrição]].Rows
        'Keyword search
        For Each kword In Split(ComboBox1.Value, " ")
            If InStr(Replace(product.Value, "", " "), kword) And kword <> "" Then
                'Issue most likely here
                clist(UBound(clist)) = product.Value
                ReDim Preserve clist(UBound(clist) + 1)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next kword
    Next product
    ReDim Preserve clist(UBound(clist) - 1)
```

Comment: This gives an error if clist is never increased in size